# Как создать в React.js option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть массив:

```
var arr = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['one', 'two', 'three']
];
```

С помощью ReactJS нужно создать `<select>` так, чтобы цикл проходил один раз по массиву, но при этом рендерил два элемента `<select>`. Первый должен содержать данные `1, 2, 3`, а второй `one, two, three`.

Таким образом, естественно, не работает:

```
arr.map(function (opt, i) {
    return <option key={i}>{opt}</option>
});
```

Подскажите, какие есть варианты?
Спасибо за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Можно создать функцию, собирающую опции элемента `<select>` и применить ее дважды к каждому из массивов исходных данных. Например так:

```
var List = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            data: [
                ['1', '2', '3'],
                ['one', 'two', 'three']
            ]
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        var mapOption = function (opt, i) {
            return (<option key={i}>{opt}</option>);
        };

        var mapSelect = function(options) {
            return (<select>{options.map(mapOption)}</select>);
        };

        return (<div>{this.state.data.map(mapSelect)}</div>);
    }
});
```

Comment: Я тоже думаю в этом направлении, но проблема в том, что <select>{mapOptions(this.state.data[0])}</select> вызывается только один раз

Comment: А сколько раз она должна вызываться? У вас в исходных данных два массива: `[1, 2, 3]` и `['one', 'two', 'three']`. Для каждого из этих массивов `mapOptions` вызовется ровно по разу, и на выходе у вас будет ровно два элемента `<select>`.

Comment: я для примера сделал 2, на самом деле они приходят с сервера и я динамически определяю их количество

Comment: @KristoferStrong, и вы хотите по элементу `select` на каждый такой массив?

Comment: да, вы правы...

Comment: @KristoferStrong, обновил ответ